# HtmlUnitDriver get mobile version (selenium framework)

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, browser, desktop

Since few days I try to use Selenium framework. I got 2 problems with this framework.

- In few case, I have the following error : "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: You may only interact with visible elements"

But my element is perfectly visible and I have only one element with this name on this page. When I change browser version this error can be avoid but it's so annoying...

- In few case, I get the mobile version of the website and I dont find any solution. How can I avoid this ?

Here is my code example on twitter :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            HtmlUnitDriver htmlUnit = new HtmlUnitDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());

            WebDriver driver = htmlUnit;

            goToTwitter(driver);

        }

public static void goToTwitter(WebDriver driver){

        driver.get("http://www.twitter.fr/login");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("session[username_or_email]"));
        WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.name("session[password]"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("****");
        element2.sendKeys("****");
        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }
```

GetCurrentUrl return "mobile.twitter.com", I need the desktop version of this site.

So my question is how can we force a website to return the desktop version with this framework ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue activating the javascript of two forms, in the selenium with the methot setJavascriptEnabled(true); and in the create newWebClient so, set directly the javascript in htmlunit

```
public HtmlUnitCustomizedWebDriver(BrowserVersion browser) {
    super(browser);
    this.setJavascriptEnabled(true);//this line

}
....
@Override
protected WebClient newWebClient(BrowserVersion version) {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(version);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(60000);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//this line
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(false);

    return webClient;
}
```

Comment: so this, I extents HtmlUnitDriver